# How can i get name of the bank, small details and company-score from html using bs4?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** elements form the url "https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings/?industry=Banks&currentpage=1

```
  <div class="company-row d-flex">
<div class="w-50">
<a class="primary-color d-block" href="../esg-rating/aecc-aviation-power-co-ltd/1031931293">AECC Aviation Power Co Ltd</a>
<small>SHG:600893</small>
</div>
<div class="company-score w-50">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">53.3</div>
<div class="col-4 d-none d-lg-block">
<div class="row cc-risk-rating-brackets">
<div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span>&amp;nbsp</span></div><div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span>&amp;nbsp</span></div><div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span>&amp;nbsp</span></div><div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span>&amp;nbsp</span></div><div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span>&amp;nbsp</span></div> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10">Severe ESG Risk</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
>>>
```

And this is my python code:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = requests.get('https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings/?industry=Aerospace+%26+Defense&currentpage=1').text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
>>> company_info = soup.find(class_='company-row d-flex')
>>> company_name = company_info.a.text
>>> company_exchange = company_info.find("small").text
>>> company_risk = soup.find("div", class_="company-score w-50").text
>>> company_risk = company_risk.split('\n')
>>> print(company_name, company_exchange, company_risk[2], company_risk[7])
AECC Aviation Power Co Ltd SHG:600893 53.3 Severe ESG Risk
>>>
```

Comment: Have you read BS4's documentation?

Comment: Yes, i have and once i get to the a tag, i am not able to parse 'href' to get Aareal Bak AG

Comment: Please post your current Python code that's using BS4 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [16]: a = """<div class="company-row d-flex">
    ...:     <div class="w-50">
    ...:     <a class="primary-color d-block" href="../esg-rating/aareal-bank-ag/1008754176">Aareal Bank AG</a>
    ...:     <small>ETR:ARL</small>
    ...:     </div>
    ...:     <div class="company-score w-50">
    ...:     <div class="row">
    ...:     <div class="col-2">22.3</div>
    ...:     <div class="col-4 d-none d-lg-block">
    ...:     <div class="row cc-risk-rating-brackets">
    ...:     <div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span> </span></div><div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span> </span></div><div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket active"><span> </span></div><div class="col cc-risk-
    ...: rating-bracket"><span> </span></div><div class="col cc-risk-rating-bracket"><span> </span></div> </div>
    ...:     </div>
    ...:     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10">Medium ESG Risk</div>
    ...:     </div>
    ...:     </div>
    ...:     </div>"""

In [17]: soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")

In [18]: data  = {}

In [19]: data["name"] = soup.find("a").get_text(strip=True)

In [20]: data["name_href"] = soup.find("a")["href"]

In [21]: data["small_text"] = soup.find("small").get_text(strip=True)

In [22]: data["company_score"] = soup.find("div", class_="row").find("div", class_="col-2").get_text(strip=True)

In [23]: data
Out[23]:
{'name': 'Aareal Bank AG',
 'name_href': '../esg-rating/aareal-bank-ag/1008754176',
 'small_text': 'ETR:ARL',
 'company_score': '22.3'}
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                      
  markup =markup.red()

Comment: Paste the full stack trace

Comment: >>> soup= BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\iafridi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 306, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>>>

Comment: I think you have to initialize `a` with the html